# Python 3.5 Pandas and MongoDB -json_normalize: raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I am trying to do data transformation using pandas on python3.5.
Data is fetched from MongoDB using MongoClient() and json_normalize. 
However when i execute below code it throws error as data argument can't be an iterator. Any pointers will help.

**Sample Data :**

```
{'bank_code': 'CID005', 'status': 'Init', 'cpgmid': '7847', 'blaze_transId': 'ZI4YQFFOTGG96ZRUQWZS121111632121509-9173782788741', 'currency': 'INR', 'amount': 7800, 'merchant_trans_id': '121111632121509-9173782788741', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 14, 1, 14, 44000), 'consumer_mobile': 9999999999.0, 'consumer_email': 'test@test.com', '_id': ObjectId('5825cf2a11eae123023730a9')}
{'bank_code': 'CID001', 'status': 'Init', 'cpgmid': '228', 'blaze_transId': '1rjfeklmg2281610111931334hjlm4j8xwl', 'currency': 'INR', 'amount': 651.4, 'merchant_trans_id': '161111569056', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 14, 1, 14, 333000), 'consumer_mobile': 9999992399.0, 'consumer_email': 'test@air.com', '_id': ObjectId('5825cf2a11eae123023730af')}
{'bank_code': 'CID001', '_id': ObjectId('5825cf2a097752b55d0f17ac'), 'custom_params': {'suppress_trans': 1}, 'currency': 'INR', 'merchant_trans_id': 'BX819215014788728725757', 'date_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 14, 1, 14, 421000), 'consumer_mobile': 0, 'status': 'Init', 'cpgmid': '1656', 'blaze_transId': '1bygejlxl16561610111931423bkgfe1uxx', 'amount': 577, 'consumer_email': 'p.25@gmail.com'}
```

**Code:**

```
start_datetime1 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=18, minute=30, second=00, microsecond=0)
start_datetime2 = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=0)).replace(hour=18, minute=29, second=59, microsecond=0)
client = MongoClient(host_val, int(port_val))
db = client.cit
transactions_collection = db.transactions

cursor = json_normalize(transactions_collection.find({'date_time': {'$lt': start_datetime2, '$gte': start_datetime1}},
                                               {'_id': 1, 'blaze_transId': 1, 'status': 1, 'merchant_trans_id': 1,
                                                'date_time': 1, 'amount': 1, 'status': 1, 'cpgmid': 1, 'currency': 1,
                                                'status_msg': 1, 'bank_code': 1, 'custom_params.suppress_trans': 1,
                                                'consumer_email': 1,'consumer_mobile': 1}))

df_txn = pd.DataFrame(cursor)
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR:root:Exception in fetch
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/Analytics-services/ETLservices/transformationService/Blazenet_Txns_Fact.py", line 174, in fetchBlazenetTxnsFromDB
'consumer_email': 1,'consumer_mobile': 1}))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/json.py", line 717, in json_normalize
    return DataFrame(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 283, in __init__
raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
```

- **TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator**

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the cursor to a list before passing it to `json_normalize`.

```
cursor = transactions_collection.find({'date_time': {'$lt': start_datetime2, '$gte': start_datetime1}},
                                               {'_id': 1, 'blaze_transId': 1, 'status': 1, 'merchant_trans_id': 1,
                                                'date_time': 1, 'amount': 1, 'status': 1, 'cpgmid': 1, 'currency': 1,
                                                'status_msg': 1, 'bank_code': 1, 'custom_params.suppress_trans': 1,
                                                'consumer_email': 1,'consumer_mobile': 1})

df_txn = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(list(cursor)))
```

You may also want to look at [monary](https://bitbucket.org/djcbeach/monary/wiki/Home) if you want to avoid having the massive ammounts of data converted to a list.

Comment: thanks a ton for quick help. so the error is not there now. but not sure why 'custom_params.suppress_trans' is not flattened. Values are shown under custom_params. If we look at data last row value - 'custom_params': {'suppress_trans': 1}.

Comment: It's hard for me to debug without seeing your dataset but you might find it easier rather than using `json_normalize` to instead use the [mongodb aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) framework with a `$match` and then a `$project` stage so the db sends back flattened documents.

Answer (score 0):

Along with Steves answer changed mongo query to avoid selecting data points which were not required. This is done to as custom_params was not getting flattened if i try to select it in mongo query.

```
cursor = transactions_collection.find({"date_time": {'$lt': start_datetime2, '$gte': start_datetime1}},{'bankRes':0,'rawDV':0})

df_txn =  pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(list(cursor)))
```